# Did Biden make it earlier to the office?

Tags: united-states, president, presidential-election, joe-biden

I've seen a video of him signing executive orders. Isn't he supposed to get to the office in March. As I remember Trump make it to the office in March. It seems everything has happened rapidly with Biden. Why so?

Comment: The simple answer is that Trump also took office in January.

Comment: Before the adoption of the [20th Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twentieth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) in 1933, the inauguration actually did take place on March 4th. Perhaps you're confusing Donald Trump with Herbert Hoover?

Comment: @divibisan I mean when the presedent elect gets to the Oval Office, already does his job.

Comment: @RS There is no president elect anymore. Biden is now the president.

Comment: @RS Every president starts work immediately after inauguration, which has been January 20th since 1933. Trump signed his first Executive Order outlining his desire to repeal the ACA [on January 20th 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Order_13765). If you think Trump didn't start until March, you're misinformed. I'm not sure where you could have heard that

Comment: This man travelled 100 years into the future...

Answer (score 5):

Trump was inaugurated on January 20th 2017 at noon which means it was the same timeframe for Biden.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inauguration_of_Donald_Trump

> The inauguration of Donald Trump as the 45th president of the United States marked the commencement of the only term of Donald Trump as president and Mike Pence as vice president.[1] An estimated 300,000 to 600,000[2][3] people attended the public ceremony held on Friday, January 20, 2017, at the West Front of the United States Capitol in Washington, D.C.

Comment: I mean time when the presedent elect gets to the Oval Office, already does his job. – R S just

Comment: @RS the POTUS does not need to be in the Oval Office to "do his job", he is the POTUS everywhere. Donald Trump was POTUS from January 20th, 2017, and was certainly "doing his job" (for example, appointing his cabinet) since January 20th.

Comment: @RS Pretty sure he entered the oval office on the 20th right after he took office. And he did sign EO's on that day.